# Do Billing Agreements even work with Paypal Payflow Pro?

Tags: payment, paypal, payment-gateway, payment-methods, billing

Is **Payflow Pro** a second rate payment method or something? I can see Billing Agreement settings for every other payment method EXCEPT Payflow Pro. Even Payflow Link has Billing Agreement Settings.

I've also seen a few modules that list their supported payment methods and everything in Magento is supported with the exception of Payflow Pro.

I've checked the Payflow Pro SDK documentation and recurring billing is supported, but Magento doesn't seem to reflect this..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Payflow Pro does not support Billing Agreements out of the box. We released an extension last year which adds a number of features to the list of things Magento can do with PayPal. Among other things the module enhances the out-of-the-box functionality to include support for credit card tokenization and *using Billing agreements with Payflow Pro*.

Since it sounds like it does just what you need, you might check it out over on Magento Connect: [PayPal Credit Card Tokenization Extension](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/paypal-credit-card-tokenization-extension.html) — For the sake of full disclosure: This extension is *free-of-charge* and open source, but it is put out by the company I work for.

Comment: For the record, dear Internet, *that's* how you answer a question which cites software you or your company wrote.

Comment: You're my hero! This is exactly what I was looking for. I will try out the module and write a review as soon as I can. Maybe you ought to consider changing the name of this module? I never would of thought to search for  "Tokenization Extension" to find this. Thanks!

Comment: Can you update the link? I am not finding it.